# How can I solve this floating point addition using this website?

Tags: floating-point

I am trying to find an easy way to solve that floating point

so I found this website

http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/koren/arith/simulator/FPAdd/

How can I use it to solve it ?

Also, How can I solve it manually ?

I don't know what to search for, I don't understand that number 2 next to 1.000, why it's a bit off the line ?

Sorry I am lost.

Hope someone can help me here.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscript is the number base, 2.  Notice how all the digits are 0's and 1's.  It's binary, base 2.  Also notice how the exponent is a power of 2.  It's binary floating point numbers.

(Here, only the [significand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand) is written in binary, the exponent and power are written in decimal.)

2<sup>-1</sup> is to divide by 2, and 2<sup>-2</sup> is to divide by 4.

Line up the digits and add them.

1<sub>2</sub> x 2<sup>-1</sup> = 0.10000<sub>2</sub> = 0.5<sub>10</sub>

-1.110<sub>2</sub> x 2<sup>-2</sup> = -0.01110<sub>2</sub> = -0.4375<sub>10</sub>

```
 0.1000 
-0.0111 +
```

See how I've lined up the decimal points?

This is basically 8 (/16) - 7 (/16), which is 1 (/16)

Now we can perform the subtraction:

```
    111 (borrow)
 0.1000
 0.0111 -
-------
 0.0001
```

aka 1/16.  Put this back into binary floating point form by making sure the first digit is a 1, and using the exponent to adjust to the value:

1.000<sub>2</sub> x 2<sup>-4</sup>

---

You'll have great difficulty using the calculator you've referenced.  It requires the numbers to be entered as hex representation of an IEEE floating point number.  While this is indeed possible, the manual computation is much more approachable.  However, to do this, I'd start here: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html.  Enter the numbers in decimal, and it will give you the hex for IEEE float.  Then you can use the other calculator.

Comment: The preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point representation is “significand.” “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm, so it is logarithmic (adding to it multiplies the value represented). A significand is linear (multiplying it multiplies the value represented).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, appreciate it!